# convert UUID as blob to proper string id hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using UUID is my id (@Id) in entity. Something like this:

```
import java.util.UUID;
@Table(name="address_book")
@Entity  
public class AddressBook {  
  @Id
  private UUID id;
  private String name;
  .
  .
  .
 }
```

Now what is happening is, when i call addressBookDao.save(addressBook) or whenever i am saving data in database it is getting stored as:

```
id, name, isbn, date, username
{blob}, john, isbn-45888, 15-02-2019, david
```

So in id column i'm getting this blob written their in every row i'm inserting. I thought UUID will generate a random id, instead of that its storing an entire json object of UUID as blob in that id column.

How can i fix this problem. I want string/random value to be present instead of blob/object?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup proper Hibernate [Generator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/mappingGuide/en-US/html/ch06.html#identifiers-generators-generic) like

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = “UUID”)
@GenericGenerator(
    name = “UUID”,
    strategy = “org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator”,
)
private UUID id;
```

Comment: still it is storing as blob

Answer (score 0):

Do you really mean BLOB? A UUID is 128 bits, certainly does not qualify for a LOB column.
For example you could use a Binary(16) column in MySQL.

Now to answer your question, you need to tell hibernate how to generate the ID value.

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "hibernate-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "hibernate-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    protected UUID id;
```

Comment: it is storing as blob

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.UUID;
@Table(name="address_book")
@Entity  
public class AddressBook {  
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(name = "name", updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)")
@Type(type = "uuid-char")
private String name;
.
.
.
}
```

this will definitely work. It worked for me and please refer to [https://www.codementor.io/@petrepopescu/how-to-use-string-uuid-in-hibernate-with-mysql-1jrhjh6ef5](https://import%20java.util.UUID;%20@Table(name=%22address_book%22)%20@Entity%20%20%20public%20class%20AddressBook%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20@Id%20%20%20@GeneratedValue(generator%20=%20%22uuid2%22)%20%20%20@GenericGenerator(name%20=%20%22uuid2%22,%20strategy%20=%20%22uuid2%22)%20%20%20@Column(name%20=%20%22name%22,%20updatable%20=%20false,%20nullable%20=%20false,%20columnDefinition%20=%20%22VARCHAR(36)%22)%20%20%20@Type(type%20=%20%22uuid-char%22)%20%20%20private%20String%20name;%20%20%20.%20%20%20.%20%20%20.%20%20%7D%20%20this%20will%20definitely%20work.%20It%20worked%20for%20me%20and%20please%20refer%20to%20https://www.codementor.io/@petrepopescu/how-to-use-string-uuid-in-hibernate-with-mysql-1jrhjh6ef5%20for%20more%20details.) for more details.